# Yii2 rest api is not returning response code and status

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to get (StatusCode) in response of REST api while its just return field name and error message like this

```
[{"field":"Email","message":"Email \"ali@ali.ali\" has already been taken."}]
```

I have added response

```
'response' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
        'on beforeSend' => function ($event) {
            $response = $event->sender;
            if ($response->data !== null && Yii::$app->request->get('suppress_response_code')) {
                $response->data = [
                    'success' => $response->isSuccessful,
                    'data' => $response->data,
                ];
                $response->statusCode = 200;
            }
        },

    ],
```

Comment: so you only set the statuscode if `suppress_response_code` is sent via `$_GET`?

Comment: But I am not getting status response in any case....

Comment: @AliRaza try to remove the second part `Yii::$app->request->get('suppress_response_code')` and test it. If it fails then `$response->data` is null.

Comment: setting controller response as "return $model;" instead of "return $model->errors;"  will automatically set appropriate status code.

Answer (score 5):

Try that way, it works for me:

```
if ("some error checking goes there") {
    Yii::$app->response->statusCode = 422;//I preferred that error code
    return [
        "data" => [
            'errors' => [
                'fieldname' => "Field Name is invalid",
            ]
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Yii::$app->response->statusCode
```

You can Add in you action this code, before return your response